# Issue in write two different types of text in android

Tags: android, textview

Hello friends i want ot write following type of text

[image]

Any idea how can i write $ in top right corner  and monthly bottom right corner in single text view?

Comment: it can be spannable string , chnage font in code

Comment: Diva : How can i make it ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Superscript<sup>` and `Subscript<sub>` tags from HTML with `HTML.fromHtml` to get required output:

```
 textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p><sup>$</sup><b>2</b><sub>Monthly</sub></p>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_currency_symbol"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txt_currency_symbol"
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/txt_value"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/txt_value"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txt_value"
        android:text="Monthly"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cSymbol"
    android:text="$"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/integer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/integer"
    android:text="2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/month"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/month"
    android:text="Month"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Output:

[image]